# how to count the number of keys in an json in front of a nested scalar wih jq

Tags: json, key, jq, depth

I have deep nested jsons and I want to count how many keys I have in front of a scalar with jq.
Here a very simplified example

```
{
    "one": {
        "two": {
            "three": [
                {
                    "four": [
                        {
                            "five": [
                                {
                                    "six": [
                                        {
                                            "sevenA": {
                                                "eightA": [
                                                    {
                                                        "nineA": "Blub"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "nineB": "def"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "nineC": "foo"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "nineD": 22
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "sevenB": {
                                                "eightB": [
                                                    {
                                                        "nineE": "Bla"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "nineF": "int"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "nineG": "s"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "nineH": 60
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

With the following command I am able to count keys and arrays in front of the scalar.

```
jq '[paths(scalars)] | map(length)'
[
  14,
  14,
  14,
  14,
  14,
  14,
  14,
  14
]
```

like this

```
  "one.two.three.[].four.[].five.[].six.[].sevenA.eightA.[].nineA",
  "one.two.three.[].four.[].five.[].six.[].sevenA.eightA.[].nineB",
  "one.two.three.[].four.[].five.[].six.[].sevenA.eightA.[].nineC",
  "one.two.three.[].four.[].five.[].six.[].sevenA.eightA.[].nineD",
  "one.two.three.[].four.[].five.[].six.[].sevenB.eightB.[].nineE",
  "one.two.three.[].four.[].five.[].six.[].sevenB.eightB.[].nineF",
  "one.two.three.[].four.[].five.[].six.[].sevenB.eightB.[].nineG",
  "one.two.three.[].four.[].five.[].six.[].sevenB.eightB.[].nineH"
```

So I get as result 14 for my example above.

But I would like to count only the keys like this.

```
".one.two.three[].four[].five[].six[].sevenB.eightB[].nineE"
".one.two.three[].four[].five[].six[].sevenB.eightB[].nineF"
".one.two.three[].four[].five[].six[].sevenB.eightB[].nineG"
".one.two.three[].four[].five[].six[].sevenB.eightB[].nineH"
".one.two.three[].four[].five[].six[].sevenB.eightB[].nineE"
".one.two.three[].four[].five[].six[].sevenB.eightB[].nineF"
".one.two.three[].four[].five[].six[].sevenB.eightB[].nineG"
".one.two.three[].four[].five[].six[].sevenB.eightB[].nineH"
```

that I count 9 keys in front of the scalar or 8 keys in front of the key value pair for the scalar.

Could somebody maybe help me how I could do this with jq?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. But `[paths(scalars)] | length` gives `8`, while `[paths(scalars) | map(strings)] | map(length)` gives an array of `9`s.

Comment: `[paths(scalars) | map(strings)] | map(length)`
This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!!!

Comment: Good. Also consider pulling `length` into the array constructor (avoiding the additional `map`): `[paths(scalars) | map(strings) | length]`

Comment: `[paths(scalars) | map(strings) | length]`
Excellent! Thank you very much! Could you maybe explain why to avoid another map?

Comment: This avoids iterating twice over the array's items. Instead, you'd use the first iteration to perform everything you want in just one go. Depending on the size of the array, this could improve your code's efficiency. (Another one could be using a reduction to count the items, avoiding to create it in the first place, if all you are interested in is its length. With smaller arrays, though, these improvements are hardly noticeable, or even reasonable wrt the (likewise important) readability of your code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce a stream of key-depths, you could write:

```
jq 'paths(scalars) | map(strings) | length' input.json
```

Or with an eye on potential efficiency enhancements, you could use the generic stream-oriented `count/1`:

```
def count(stream):
  reduce stream as $_ (0; .+1);

paths(scalars) | count(.[] | strings)
```

Or to compute the maximum key depth using a generic stream-oriented "max" function:

```
def count(stream):
  reduce stream as $_ (0; .+1);

# max(empty) is empty
def max(stream):
  reduce (stream | [.]) as $x (null;
    if . == null or $x > . then $x else . end )
  | if . == null then empty else .[0] end;

max(paths(scalars) | count(.[] | strings))
```